# InProc Session for ASP.NET CORE MVC not working on IIS

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc

I am looking for help and advice regarding session state(InProc) is null when asp.net core mvc 6.0 is hosted on IIS.

I have read a number of blogs but those solutions suggested do not seem to be working to me.

Session state working fine when my web app is launched with ipaddress + port(other than 80) but broken when browse with registered domain name.

What mistake I have done?

I have attach my codes for your reference. Do let me know if you need further info.

```
// Program.cs

builder.Services.ConfigureAntiforgeryOptions();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddCookieTempDataProvider();

builder.Services.ConfigureIocScanOptions();
builder.Services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                options.Cookie.Name = ".WebApp.Session";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Auth}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();


// Extension to set and get session variable value 
public static class SessionExtensions
    {
        public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
        }

        public static T? Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how you set the domain for your IIS application? It's subdomain or the else? Since the session ID will store as cookie inside the client side, it looks the client missed the sessionID.

Comment: @BrandoZhang, I am able navigate to my login page with registered domain name, but session variable is empty after I login. I didn't do any domain settings on IIS. Could you tell me how? Shall I create a new user with domain name on window server 2019?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you register the domain name? By using the IIS site binding or else?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I register a domain name from namecheap and bind the registered domain name with my host ipaddress from namecheap. I didnt do any IIS configuration to bind my host ipaddress with domain name.